# При изменении текста label сдвигаются кнопки.Python Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

```
   import tkinter as tk
   
   win=tk.Tk()
   win.geometry("400x350")
   win['bg']='#33ffe6'
   def add_number(sim):
       label['text']=label['text']+sim
   def rezult():
       label['text']=eval(label['text'])
   
   label=tk.Label(win,text='',padx=200,pady=10)
   
   label.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=4,stick='we')
   tk.Button(text='1',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('1')).grid(row=1,column=0,stick='wesn')
   tk.Button(text='2',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('2')).grid(row=1,column=1,stick='wesn')
   tk.Button(text='3',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('3')).grid(row=1,column=2,stick='wesn')
   tk.Button(text='4',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('4')).grid(row=2,column=0,stick='wesn')
   tk.Button(text='5',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('5')).grid(row=2,column=1,stick='wesn')
   tk.Button(text='6',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('6')).grid(row=2,column=2,stick='wesn')
   tk.Button(text='7',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('7')).grid(row=3,column=0,stick='wesn')
   tk.Button(text='8',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('8')).grid(row=3,column=1,stick='wesn')
   tk.Button(text='9',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('9')).grid(row=3,column=2,stick='wesn')
   tk.Button(text='+',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('+')).grid(row=1,column=3,stick='wesn')
   tk.Button(text='-',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('-')).grid(row=2,column=3,stick='wesn')
   tk.Button(text='*',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('*')).grid(row=3,column=3,stick='wesn')
   tk.Button(text='=',pady=20,command=lambda:rezult()).grid(row=4,column=3,stick='wesn')
   
   
   win.mainloop()
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Answer (score 0):

у меня получилось это сделать, но я не уверен лучшим ли образом.
я использовал команду win.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1), она останавливает изменения размера виджетов в 0 колонке из-за этого интерфейс немного съехал но, я попытался все исправить, на каждой кнопке использовал padx=50 для изменения размера по оси X
кнопки больше не сдвигаются но интерфейс все же немного поменялся вот код

```
    import tkinter as tk

    win=tk.Tk()
    win.geometry("400x350")
    win['bg']='#33ffe6'
    def add_number(sim):
        label['text']=label['text']+sim
    def rezult():
        label['text']=eval(label['text'])

    win.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

    label=tk.Label(win,text='',padx=200,pady=10)

    label.grid(row=0,column=0,columnspan=4,stick='we')
    tk.Button(text='1',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('1'),padx=50).grid(row=1,column=0,stick='wesn',columnspan=1)
    tk.Button(text='2',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('2'),padx=50).grid(row=1,column=1,stick='wesn',columnspan=1)
    tk.Button(text='3',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('3'),padx=50).grid(row=1,column=2,stick='wesn',columnspan=1)
    tk.Button(text='4',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('4'),padx=50).grid(row=2,column=0,stick='wesn',columnspan=1)
    tk.Button(text='5',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('5'),padx=50).grid(row=2,column=1,stick='wesn',columnspan=1)
    tk.Button(text='6',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('6'),padx=50).grid(row=2,column=2,stick='wesn',columnspan=1)
    tk.Button(text='7',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('7'),padx=50).grid(row=3,column=0,stick='wesn',columnspan=1)
    tk.Button(text='8',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('8'),padx=50).grid(row=3,column=1,stick='wesn',columnspan=1)
    tk.Button(text='9',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('9'),padx=50).grid(row=3,column=2,stick='wesn',columnspan=1)
    tk.Button(text='+',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('+'),padx=50).grid(row=1,column=3,stick='wesn',columnspan=1)
    tk.Button(text='-',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('-'),padx=50).grid(row=2,column=3,stick='wesn',columnspan=1)
    tk.Button(text='*',pady=20,command=lambda:add_number('*'),padx=50).grid(row=3,column=3,stick='wesn',columnspan=1)
    tk.Button(text='=',pady=20,command=lambda:rezult()).grid(row=4,column=3,stick='wesn',columnspan=1)


    win.mainloop()
```